# WPF - Is there a built-in toolbar which adds new lines whenever space is needed?

Tags: wpf, toolbar, multiline

I have this toolbar with toggle buttons.

When I check a button, controls appear. But if I enable all options, there won't be any space left in the toolbar. Is there any way to place these controls in another toolbar "line" automatically?

Something like this:

**| togglebutton | options | togglebutton |** <- ops, endofline

**| options | another togglebutton** <- this is the second line

I get the feeling I'll have to develop this myself.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find that the `WrapPanel` is a good place to start with this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel.aspx

Simply place the contents of your toolbar in a WrapPanel and let WPF do the rest.